# Foreground notification not displaying in notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-9.0-pie

The new code for notification channel is working fine in older and latest device of oreo but when I tested in API 28(android P) device it didn't show the notification in notification bar,  this is the line I've used for start the foreground notification.

```
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: How are you constructing the notification?

Comment: also what is your `NOTIFICATION_ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target Android 9.0 (API level 28)

- Need to add [`FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground) in manifest.

> Note: Apps that target Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher and use
>   foreground services must request the FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission.
>   This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to
>   the requesting app.

**In Manifest add permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```